# INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS error in Android 8

Tags: android, crash, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I have two different users in my Android device and the app I'm developing works properly in the main user, but when I switch to a different Android user, I get a crash triggered because of the next error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: get package info: Neither user 1110776
>   nor current process has android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS.
>                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942)
>                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
>                                                   at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.getAuthToken(IAccountManager.java:1488)
>                                                   at android.accounts.AccountManager$11.doWork(AccountManager.java:1749)
>                                                   at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask.start(AccountManager.java:2240)
>                                                   at android.accounts.AccountManager.getAuthToken(AccountManager.java:1746)
>                                                   at android.accounts.AccountManager.getAuthToken(AccountManager.java:1658)
>                                                   at android.accounts.AccountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(AccountManager.java:1495)

My app basically has a login and I use the AccountManager to get an auth token by using the method [AccountManager.blockingGetAuthToken](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#blockingGetAuthToken(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)). In the main user, I can use that method properly and the login works fine, but when I switch to the second user, I get the error and crash just after calling that method.

This only happens in Android 8, in previous versions the app works as expected for all the Android users in my device.

I've tried to grant the **INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS** permissions in some way but is an special permission, not accessible from third party applications.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Without a [mcve] and a description of what your app is doing before and after the user switch, it will be difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare , I've just included more information in the question about what the app does. Thanks